# SonarQube Webb analyse jsp

Tags: java, jsp, sonarqube

I want to use SonarQube to analyse my jsp filesw among others.
Now I know That it is possible to do this via the settings menu. Settings->Web and add .jsp to the File suffixes.

Now I'm wondering if this is also possible to config this via the Pom.xml?

```
 <sonar.web.file.suffixes>.html,.xhtml,.rhtml,.shtml,.jsp</sonar.web.file.suffixes>
```

doesn't seem to have affect

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the config in your pom.xml under properties or add .jsp to your web setting in sonar server(General Setting > Web)